# Why is ffmpeg adding duplicates of my audio files to my video?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to add a list of audio files to a video, with each audio file starting a different time (using the `adelay` filter). Although each audio gets added to the video at the correct time, it's also added to the very beginning of the video. So the start of the video has all the audio files playing at once.

Here's the ffmpeg command I'm using.

```
ffmpeg -i silent.mp4 -i tmp/0-cropped.mp3 -i tmp/1-cropped.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=1000[a1d];[2]adelay=2000[a2d];[a1d][a2d]amix=2[a]" -y -map 0:v -map [a] with-audio.mp4;
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else finding this, the issue was that the audio files were stereo, not mono. So I guess one channel was being added where I specified, and the other was just being added to the beginning.

The following change fixes the problem:

```
ffmpeg -i silent.mp4 -i tmp/0-cropped.mp3 -i tmp/1-cropped.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=1000|1000[a1d];[2]adelay=2000|2000[a2d];[a1d][a2d]amix=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -y with-audio.mp4;
```

Comment: adelay has an option to apply delay to all channels e.g. `adelay=1000:all=1`. Requires v4.3 or later.